# Sticky columns don't stay within their parent div

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Why are the columns not glued to their parent div? When scrolling the sticky left and right containers scroll on top of the RecommendedProducts div. The expected behavior is that they should stop/stick when they've reached the bottom of their containing parent.

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-darkness-uefhr2?file=/src/index.js

```html
 <>
      <div className="h-full w-screen">
        <div className="bg-[#EFEFEF] relative h-auto w-full pt-12">
          {images &&
            images.map((image) => (
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center" key={image.id}>
                <div className="relative h-[calc(100vh-48px)] w-full">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.ibb.co/mDTWnb2/hej.webp"
                    alt={image.alt}
                    className="object-contain w-full h-full"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}

          <div className="fixed top-0 w-full">
            <div className="mx-auto flex w-11/12 flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-8 sm:grid sm:w-full sm:max-w-screen-3xl sm:grid-cols-3 sm:space-y-0 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              {/* Desktop */}

              {/* Left column */}
              <div className="flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center self-start sm:sticky sm:inset-y-0">
                <div className="flex w-[300px] flex-col items-center justify-start bottom-0 overflow-y-auto">
                  <ProductDescription />
                </div>
              </div>

              {/* Middle column */}
              <div className="hidden sm:block"></div>

              {/* Right column */}
              <div className="flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center self-start sm:sticky sm:inset-y-0">
                <div className="flex w-[200px] flex-col items-center justify-start bottom-0 overflow-y-auto">
                  <ProductDescription />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <RecommendedProducts />
    </>
```

Comment: JS solutions accepted as well, not sure if this can be solved with just css as the parent div is floated on top of the div with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: sticky` requires that (i) the parent element has a `height` property; (ii) a threshold has been specified with a property like `top`, `bottom`, `right`, or `left`.

So to achieve the behavior I believe you want in your example, you need to do two things:

(i) Set a `height` to the `div` that's acting as the columns container. If you want to keep it flexible, you cant set its `height` and also its parent's `height` to `full`. In tailwind that's the `h-full` class.

(ii) Add `position: sticky` and `top: 0` properties to the columns. In Tailwind that's the `sticky` and `top-0` classes.

```html
<div className="h-full absolute top-0 w-full">
  <div className="h-full mx-auto items-center justify-center grid w-full max-w-screen-3xl grid-cols-3 px-8">
    {/* Left column */}
    <div className="sticky top-0 flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center self-start">
      <div className="flex w-[300px] flex-col items-center justify-start bottom-0 overflow-y-auto">
        <ProductDescription />
      </div>
    </div>

    {/* Middle column */}
    <div className="hidden sm:block"></div>

    {/* Right column */}
    <div className="sticky top-0 flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center self-start">
      <div className="flex w-[200px] flex-col items-center justify-start bottom-0 overflow-y-auto">
        <ProductDescription />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The code in the snippet and in the sandbox you provided have different classes. I edited the one in the sandbox to provide the answer above.